# Tabularx Multirow has different border width

Tags: tables, tabularx, border

I'm creating a table using tabularx package. The problem comes when I add a multirow. The multirow borders are different (the border width is smaller) and I don't know how to fix this issue.

[image]

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  |p{\dimexpr.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|
  }
    \hline
    AA & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla} \\
    \hline
    BB & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla} \\
    \hline
    CC & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla} \\
    \hline
    DD & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{blablabla} & 1. & aaa \\
    & 2. & bbb \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{blablabla} & 1. & aaa \\
    & 2. & bbb \\
    \hline
    EE & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: As always please post a full minimal example instead of a snippet like this. This makes it a lot easier for others to test the issue. Are you sure this is not just a viewer artifact? Is the issue still there when you zoom in?

Comment: @daleif It's still there if I zoom in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your

```
\multicolumn{2}{|X|}{blablabla}
```

vertical rules are on the righthand edge of the cell, except in the first column, so on that row you have a `|` from the previous cell and an additional `|` on the left of this cell, so it appears double thickness (but is actually two rules, side by side). just use `X|`

In this example where all column widths are known in advance, `tabularx` is doing nothing useful and I would use a normal `tabular` but the same `|` issue would apply.